# handling text file in awk and making a new file

Tags: awk

I have a text file like this small example:

```
chr10:102721669-102724893   3217    3218    5
chr10:102721669-102724893   3218    3219    1
chr10:102721669-102724893   3219    3220    5
chr10:102721669-102724893   421 422 1
chr10:102721669-102724893   858 859 2
chr10:102539319-102568941   13921   13922   1
chr10:102587299-102589074   1560    1561    1
chr10:102587299-102589074   1565    1566    1
chr10:102587299-102589074   1595    1596    1
chr10:102587299-102589074   944 945 1
```

the expected output would look like this:

```
chr10:102721669-102724893   3217    3218    5   CA
chr10:102721669-102724893   3218    3219    1   CA
chr10:102721669-102724893   3219    3220    5   CA
chr10:102721669-102724893   421 422 1   BA
chr10:102721669-102724893   858 859 2   BA
chr10:102539319-102568941   13921   13922   1   NON
chr10:102587299-102589074   1560    1561    1   CA  
chr10:102587299-102589074   1565    1566    1   CA
chr10:102587299-102589074   1595    1596    1   CA
chr10:102587299-102589074   944 945 1   BA
```

the input has `4 tab separated` columns and in the output, I have one more column with 3 different class (`CA, NON or BA`).
1- if the `1st column` in the input is not repeated, in the `5th column` of output it will be classified as NON
2- if `(the number just after ":" (in the 1st column) + the 2nd column) - the number just after "-" (in the 1st column) is smaller than -30 (meaning -31 or smaller), that line will be classified as BA`. for example in the last line:
`(102587299 + 944) - 102589074 = -831 , so this line is classified as BA`.

3- if `(the number just after ":" (in the 1st column) + the 2nd column) - the number just after "-" (in the 1st column) is equal or bigger than -30 (meaning -30 or -29), that line will be classified as CA`. for example the 1st line:

```
(102721669 + 3217) - 102724893 = -7
```

I am trying to do that in `awk`.

```
awk -F "\t"":""-" '{if($2+$4-$3 < -30) ; print $7 = BA,  if($2+$4-$3 >= -30) ; print $7 = CA}' file.txt > out.txt
```

but it does not returns what I expect. do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} NR==FNR{a[$1]++; next}
       { split($1, b, /[\t:-]/);
         $5 = a[$1]==1 ? "NON" : (b[2]+$2-b[3]) < -30 ? "BA" : "CA" }
       1' file.txt file.txt
chr10:102721669-102724893   3217    3218    5   CA
chr10:102721669-102724893   3218    3219    1   CA
chr10:102721669-102724893   3219    3220    5   CA
chr10:102721669-102724893   421 422 1   BA
chr10:102721669-102724893   858 859 2   BA
chr10:102539319-102568941   13921   13922   1   NON
chr10:102587299-102589074   1560    1561    1   BA
chr10:102587299-102589074   1565    1566    1   BA
chr10:102587299-102589074   1595    1596    1   BA
chr10:102587299-102589074   944 945 1   BA
```

- `BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}` set both input/output field separator as tab
- `NR==FNR{a[$1]++; next}` to count how many times first field is present in the file. Input file is passed twice, so that on second pass we can make decision based on count
- `split($1, b, /[\t:-]/)` split the first column further, results saved in `b` array
- rest of the code is assigning 5th field depending on given conditions and printing the modified line

**Further reading**

- [Idiomatic awk](http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/)
- [split function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#index-split_0028_0029-function)