# how do I use awk to edit a file

Tags: awk

I have a text file like this small example:

```
chr10:103909786-103910082   147 148 24  BA
chr10:103909786-103910082   149 150 11  BA
chr10:103909786-103910082   150 151 2   BA
chr10:103909786-103910082   152 153 1   BA
chr10:103909786-103910082   274 275 5   CA
chr10:103909786-103910082   288 289 15  CA
chr10:103909786-103910082   294 295 4   CA
chr10:103909786-103910082   295 296 15  CA
chr10:104573088-104576021   2925    2926    134 CA
chr10:104573088-104576021   2926    2927    10  CA
chr10:104573088-104576021   2932    2933    2   CA
chr10:104573088-104576021   58  59  1   BA
chr10:104573088-104576021   689 690 12  BA
chr10:104573088-104576021   819 820 33  BA
```

in this file there are 5 `tab separated` columns. the first column is considered as ID. for example in the first row the whole "`chr10:103909786-103910082`" is ID.

`1-` in the 1st step I would like to filter out the rows based on the 4th column. 
if the number in the `4th column is less than 10` and the same row but in the `5th column the group is BA`, that row will be filtered out. also if the number in the `4th column is less than 5` and the same row but in the `5th column the group is CA`, that row will be filtered out.

`3-` 3rd step:
I want to get the ratio of number in `4th column`. in fact in the `1st column` there are repeated values which represent the same `ID`. I want to get one ratio per `ID`, so in the output every `ID` will be repeated only once. each `ID` has both `BA` and `CA` in the `5th column`. for each `ID` I should get 2 values for `CA` and `BA` separately and get the ration of `CA/BA` as the final value for each `ID`. to get one value as `CA`, I should add up all values in the `4th column` which belong the same `ID` and classified as `CA` and to get one value as `BA`, I should add up all values in the `4th column` which belong the same `ID` and classified as `BA`. the last step is to get the ration of `CA/BA` per `ID`. the expected output for the small example would look like this:

`1- after filtration`:

```
chr10:103909786-103910082   147 148 24  BA
chr10:103909786-103910082   149 150 11  BA
chr10:103909786-103910082   274 275 5   CA
chr10:103909786-103910082   288 289 15  CA
chr10:103909786-103910082   295 296 15  CA
chr10:104573088-104576021   2925    2926    134 CA
chr10:104573088-104576021   2926    2927    10  CA
chr10:104573088-104576021   689 690 12  BA
chr10:104573088-104576021   819 820 33  BA
```

`2- after summarizing each group` (`CA` and `BA`):

```
chr10:103909786-103910082   147 148 35  BA
chr10:103909786-103910082   274 275 35  CA
chr10:104573088-104576021   2925    2926    144 CA
chr10:104573088-104576021   819 820 45  BA
```

3- the `final output`(this ratio is made using the values in 4th column):

```
chr10:103909786-103910082   1
chr10:104573088-104576021   3.2
```

in the above lines, 1 = 35/35 and 3.2 = 144/45.

I am trying to do that in `awk`

```
awk 'ID==$1 {
         if (ID) {
             print ID, a["CA"]/a["BA"]; a["CA"]=a["BA"]=0;
         }
         ID=$1
     }
     $5=="BA" && $4>=10 || $5=="CA" && $4>=5 { a[$5]+=$4 }
     END{ print ID, a["CA"]/a["BA"] }' file.txt
```

I tried to use the code but did not succeed. this code returns one number. in fact sum of all CA and divides it by sum of all `BAs` but I want to do that per ID and get the ration per ID. do you know how to solve the problem and correct the code?

Comment: also, possibly same person posting with different accounts - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48852411/combining-different-operations-in-a-text-file-using-awk

Comment: Possible duplicate of [handling text file in awk and making a new file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48842382/handling-text-file-in-awk-and-making-a-new-file)

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '$4 >= 5 && $5 == "CA" { a[$1]+=$4 }
     $4 >= 10 && $5 == "BA" { b[$1]+=$4 }
     END{ for ( i in a) print i,a[i]/b[i]}' file
```

output:

```
chr10:103909786-103910082 1
chr10:104573088-104576021 3.2
```